# Use Salesforce Sites page in an iFrame on external site

Tags: force.com-sites, attachment, web-to-case

I have a requirement to allow web-to-case form to upload attachments. Now, as per the [**docs**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000188389&type=1) there are two possible ways to do so:

- Implement Visualforce pages in Force.com Sites.
- Using Force.com web services API implementation.

I opted for the former solution, i.e. VF page in Force.com Sites. All is working fine, but I have to use that page in 5 different client sites. So, I proposed, to use the VF page inside an [iFrame](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp), so the branding of the site would override the VF page with the header and footer, etc.

I tried that myself first on Blogger to see if the idea works as I hoped it would! (see below)

[image]

> Workarounds available at my disposal:

- Create 5 different VF pages with specific styling related to each site brand and then share each VF page with specific team.

  - Problem: any change in requirements or fields would need to me change every VF page.

> Question

Is there a way to display my Force.com Site VF page on external site with their branding?

Comment: Create a dynamic page that accepts the brand as a url parameter. You then could use custom objects/meta data to handle the changes via clicks rather than code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to display my site's page on external in an iFrame by following method

- goto Site settings from setup
- set the "Clickjack Protection Level" to "Allow framing by any page (no protection)"
- press "Save"

---

[image]

---

Review ["Load denied by X-Frame-Options: URL does not permit framing.' error message"](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000264792&language=en_US&type=1) for more details.